# Nothing to do, no schemas or tables selected on export

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, export

I'm using MySql Workbench 6.3.6, on Windows 10, which has all updates.

I have previously been able to get a data dump from this database. Now I can't get any from any of the schemas I have open in workbench.

I've been able to run queries and make changes to the databases.

Then when I try to use the export function I get this message:

> Nothing to do, no schemas or tables selected.

[image]

I have found some bug reports, but am not convinced they apply to version 6.3.6:

[mysqlbugs](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=49110)

[ubuntu mysql workbench](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-workbench/+bug/1108630)

---

File bug report http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79866&thanks=4

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall workbench from system and install it back.
Problem mainly occurs with the some where file distribution might be corrupted.